# How to use a search box to filter by class name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, filter

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help, I'm trying to make it so when you search in a search box if a div contains a word you entered in the box it will show and if not it will hide. This is what I have so far but now I'm stuck, I have researched but I only have a basic knowledge of Javascript and I can't seem to get any further. Thank you!

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  
  
  $('div').find('div').each(function(){
     var className = $(this).attr("class");
     
  });
      
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test"><h1>hello 1</h1></div>
    <div class="no"><h1>hello 2</h1></div>
    <div class="no"><h1>hello 3</h1></div>
    <div class="test"><h1>hello 4</h1></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What ae you entering the search?  "test" and "no"?  Or "hello"?  Your question title suggests you want to find "test" (*filter by class name*) and your code gets the class.   Your question text says "*if a div contains a word*".

Comment: Sorry I did mean filter by class name.

Answer (score 1):

Taking these two requirements:

> contains a word
>
> filter by class name

You can filter by class name by using a selector "."+classname, eg `.test`, so you can combine the input text with "." and use that as a selector.

```
$(".wrapper>div."+filter).show();
```

When combining like this, you do need to check for items that will make the query break (eg empty value) - might be better to have a `select` for this, which would also reduce typos.

If you use a jquery event (as already using jquery), `this` will be the input, so you can get the filter with a simple:

```
var filter = $(this).val();
```

There's various ways to show/hide/toggle, here's one method, combining the above.

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
  
  $(".wrapper>div").hide();
  if (filter !== "") 
    $(".wrapper>div."+filter).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
    <h1>hello 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="no">
    <h1>hello 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="no">
    <h1>hello 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <h1>hello 4</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method in jQuery returns the text content of the specified element and removes any markup inside it. What you would want to do is loop through all divs, get their text content and pass it through `includes` to check if any part of the search text matches. If it does, you show it using jQuery `show()` method and hide it using `hide()` method. Also, you don't need to use `find('div')`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  
  
  $('div').each(function(){
     var divTextContent = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
     if (divTextContent.includes(filter)){
       $(this).show();
     } else {
       $(this).hide();
     }
  });
      
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test"><h1>hello 1</h1></div>
    <div class="no"><h1>hello 2</h1></div>
    <div class="no"><h1>hello 3</h1></div>
    <div class="test"><h1>hello 4</h1></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No issues with the approach, but you might like to consider .filter to reduce your "loop" to a one-liner.